# Дизайн плитки вопроса с принятым ответом

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Небольшие стилевые изменения на ruSO, конечно, хорошо, но вот при просмотре списка вопросов стало сложно отличить вопросы, на которые просто дали ответ и вопросы - где ответ приняли. Потому, что цвет и в том и в другом случае зеленый.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, там, где ответ был принят - чуть потемнее, но все равно если они не расположены рядом - непонятно. Да и если подряд идут все равно как-то одинаково выглядят.
А если у человека с восприятием оттенков проблема?

Может стоит все что-то чуть более отличительное сделать? Галку или......Таньку (тупой юмор).

К примеру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не дизайнер...поэтому такой цвет и решение)) 
Но это пример для того, кто занимается дизом сайта)
Может стоит добавить

**Повторю еще раз более точно:** Я не говорю, что надо цвет поменять, просто, мне кажется, нужно чуть более выразительней разницу сделать...банальной галкой или каким-то дополнением, при котором глаз мог бы быстрее поймать подобное отличие

p.s. я не знаю куда писать такого рода предложения.

Comment: У меня предложение на Мете оставить, цвета, какие были, дабы лучше различать, на каком сайте находишься в данную минуту. Насчёт галочек согласен — общепринятый символ.

Comment: Это в любом случае лучше чем было раньше :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov не спорю. дя я не говорю, что нужно координально поменять, но чуть большее отличие должно быть.....банально галку добавить

Comment: Я бы еще цветом цифры отмечал примерную сумму голосов за ответы.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321414/4928642

Comment: @Qwertiy уже все прочитал)

Comment: Зачем эти "птички", зачем этот мусор? И так всё ясно было. Если нет принятого ответа, то квадрат без фона, Если что-то принято - то с фоном. Нафига всё усложнять. Тем более надо учитывать, что "интеллектуальным" трудом заняты в основном мужчины, среди которых дальтонизм более вероятен, чем у противоположного пола. Не всякий различит не то что красное от зелёного, но и оттенки одного цвета.

Comment: @Sergey так было светлоЗеленый-темноЗеленый, а не  безФона -зеленый.......это все равно что светофор будет не красным-желтым-зеленым, а бледноЗеленым-СреднеТемноЗеленым-ТемноЗеленым .... смотри также http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2884/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC#comment9050_2885      ........ а вообще пора оставить этот вопрос)

Answer (score 5):

Они настолько разные, что в одном используется тёмно-зелёное число на светло-зелёном фоне, а в другом белое число на тёмно зелёном. Т. е. цвет текста непринятого ответа почти совпадает с цветом фона принятого. Не представляю, как их можно не различить.

Comment: Но выделение избранных меток, полагаю довольно [тускловато](https://i.gyazo.com/d76ac0ce022dddf3de59cd3027ba66ea.png).

Comment: Да тогда можно можно все сделать зеленым, просто разными оттенками))) .........Спокойно можно не различить. Например если монитор находится не ровно параллельно глазам, а под некоторым углом. Цвет начинает сливаться...Да даже если параллельно, все равно ответы под разными углами находятся...... Или, как я уже писал, у кого есть проблемы с восприятием тонов... Да и логически как-то бестолково - зеленый для одного, зеленый для другого, можно еще зеленым фон сделать)) Они должны как-то по-другому отличаться. явно, а не неявно.

Comment: @СашаЧерных для избранных можно предложить чтобы сделали Супер темно темно зеленый цвет, чтоб уж выдерживать стиль)))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если предположить, что ты не можешь различить эти два фона, это будет означать, что ты не можешь различить текст с числом ответов в случае отсутствия принятого. Но ведь это не так, иначе об этом бы и говорилось в вопросе. Получается, проблемы всё-таки нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy Текст не сильно выделяется на фоне, не бросается  в глаза. Поэтому не происходит его сравнение с чем-л., он просто воспринимается как должное.....  Это как волосатая черная бородавка прямо на щеке человека - сразу привлекает внимание, или как в индии точка на лбу - сложно сразу не обратить на нее внимание. Так же и тут - достаточно что-то такое добавить, что сразу бросается в глаза, чтоб понять отличие.....

Answer (score 4):

Ну вот, перекрасили в белый с зелёной рамкой.

Comment: Это не я. Я не просил менять цвет)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, поменялось на всех сайтах. Видимо, не только тебе раскраска не понравилась. А вообще, пожалуй, так действительно лучше стало :)

Comment: Так она мне не не нравилась до такой степени)  Я все равно даже до сих пор считаю что какая-нибудь блямба на правильном ответе должна присутствовать) А по цвету претензий и не было) ...... а цвет плитки где ответ еще не был принят мне кста больше нравился чем просто рамка))) но я не дизайнер....уж у SO есть спецы наверное, которые сделают как надо в итоге

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не знаю, какие там спецы, но на мой взгляд все это теперь смотрится убого.

Comment: @avp я написал: "наверное" =)  я был только за галку)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а я посмотрел на это в целом.